# Input validation problem. Trying to make make it so that the user cannot input a negative number. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make so when the user inputs a negative number, the input validation will say they cannot, and then my code will continue by re-asking the user the original prompt. My problem is, is that its not registering the numbers are positive or negative, only running through the code as if the number doesn't have a value? I'm not sure, I'm a bit lost.

while True:

```
mph = float(input('What is the speed of the vehicle '))

hours = float(input('How many hours has it traveled '))

if mph or hours < 0:

    print ('That was a negative number, answer the questions again. ')

    mph = float(input('What is the speed of the vehicle '))

    hours = float(input('How many hours has it traveled '))

distance = mph * hours

print ('Miles traveled:', distance)

break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with:

```
if mph or hours < 0:
```

You are thinking about this in an English language sense, rather than a Python sense. i.e. You are thinking "if mph or hours is less than zero". A human would understand this, but Python interprets this differently. Don't worry, this is a very common mistake when people start programming; you'll soon get used to it.

What you actually want is:

```
if mph < 0 or hours < 0:
```

Because your original comparisons actually say to Python: "If mph is anything other than 0 or hours is less than zero". Or, in code:

```
if not 0 or hours < 0
```

This is because of the concept of [truthy and falsy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) values.

You might want to also consider replacing the two lines that ask for the same input again (if negative values are entered) with a `continue` statement. Because, as it's currently written, there is a problem if the user enters incorrect information for a second time. Test your code in this way (deliberately enter negative numbers twice in a row) to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up making them two separate while loops and it worked great for me!

Comment: You are most welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you find any answers/questions useful, when using the site, please consider upvoting them or marking them as accepted answer if you asked the question (but you can't do both. i.e. You can't mark as accepted and upvote the same answer). Please note however that you can't upvote answers (where you are not the author of the question) until you get a rep of at least 50.

Comment: Thank you! I've heard about this site from my friend, but I still don't know much about the community, good to know!